API Gateway - getting not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header while accessing the cart data for kfc

I am getting this error while trying to access the data for KFC items added in cart. This error is not arising when I simply intercept the request using Postman interceptor but when I try to change the body of post request to add another item to cart, this error arises.
I tried using the authorization token by manually inserting it, but it seems an error arose due to some other reasons.
the following code is giving 401 error:
import requests

url = "https://orderserv-kfc-apac-olo-api.yum.com/dev/v1/baskets/718f36cc-bb6f-4c87-a057-ef098138a635"

# Define the correct headers, excluding pseudo-headers
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJPMTlpTGtNYnN6eHc2Wm9TejRLbDIwTEhIY1NmcVppbmZLN0p4ZkZGaVc4In0.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.TqBHm_Fbz3Codt1U4U0J3X6fC54lE5RSvtXMtrcAfTt7m_fl1A13Ig0Th0wZq7pgHUpuhiCyze0517kI7VefBUU-XoMuNgBhhde48V0VE5yIQXqrxT2R_xfvx9EEWpxPyBo_oEojr0avvNtR5va3mNRtJRi0S_K0yC0zuILNLeQ-UwgeIRNQOpBN-PquuY9k4bd-QxU9Bc7pcOcnkoTymdI4NViXa8_VffC5lfDJ9AcuInzxLDRzZtxt9semQRqoplpzPED-QtSVyIl_F40akIjdXMilJ-GInUFDmMJQi423emoNXD5aiq4mw9GRGi4FUjjMitdk7oS8E2cybzANhg",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    
}

# Send the GET request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful

if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve data. Status code: {response.status_code}")

